# Is there something better than django-piston?

Tags: python, django, rest

With 145 forks, 125 open issues, and the last release almost 2years ago, django-piston appears to be approaching abandonware and since the project I'm working on is likely to be a big one, I'd like to standardise on something that's going to be around for a while.  Is there something resembling a consensus in the Python/Django community regarding a preference for REST API services?  Even if it's one of those 145 forks?  Ideally, I'd like to find something that plays nice with @jacobian's [REST Worst Practises](http://jacobian.org/writing/rest-worst-practices/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django Piston project seems to be abandonned.
[Django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) has taken a large advantage with its second version.

Note that this is valid for now (2014), time may decide different.

Answer (score 28):

check http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/api/ (django-tastypie looks very promising)

I also don't like Piston very much. Don't misunderstand me. It is (or was) a good app, though it has its issues. The main problem I had working with it that it hides Debugging information coming from django.

If you are absolutely unsure about what to use roll your own. With django 1.3 and class based views you got already a good way to add an API like this. If you need OAuth or other authentication methods you can simply check existing ways in piston or other apps and use them.

Answer (score 17):

Two other REST packages that may be of interest :

- http://django-rest-framework.org/
- http://benoitc.github.com/dj-webmachine/index.html

Answer (score 10):

It is worth mentioning about 
[django-tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie)

This is getting faster acceptance than the others.

Comment: tastypie is dead now